# htaccess rewrite not working if file exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to write rewrite rule than will always rewrite to single file, use same query parameters and add "f" query parameter as originally requested file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ authorize.php?f=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

http://domain/sample2.pdf - EXPECTED - executes authorize.php (sample2 does not exist)

http://domain/sample.pdf - UNEXPECTED - opens sample.pdf file (exists in folder)

Comment: Is `authorize.php` loaded first then redirecting to `sample.pdf`? What is the response if you do `curl http://domain/sample.pdf -I`?

Comment: Something else is wrong, outside of that htaccess file. I've tested it, and it works fine. Please see: https://dev.cratrr.com/74852212/sample.pdf

Comment: @user3783243, same response, browser cache was issue. After clearing it, it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan browser cache was issue. After clearing it, it works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turnsed out browser cache was issue. After clearing it, it works as expected. Found it out thanks to Jordan's comment.